# Using SQLQuery.uniqueResult() to perform native SQL INSERTs and UPDATEs

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, insert, native

I am using Hibernate in my project and there is a certain scenario where I want to use the **uniqueResult()** method on the **org.hibernate.SQLQuery** class to perform native SQL **INSERT** and **UPDATE** operations.

I did try using the **executeUpdate()** method on the same class. But I get an error saying that they are used for HQL updates only.

Please advice if this is effective and reliable way of ensuring data being saved/updated in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session.createSQLQuery()` is for querying, not manipulation. If you want to do raw SQL insert, use `session.connection()` and straight JDBC code.

Not sure why you need this exactly but I'd also suggest to check [16.3. Custom SQL for create, update and delete](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. But, would session.connection() work within the transaction boundaries of the current Hibernate Session?

Actually I want to execute the native SQL for some inserts and updates and need to do it with raw SQL for performance reasons. Besides i'm working with a database whose schema is not designed/optimized on entities and so I have trouble getting Hibernate to work well with it.

I am doing some inserts using uniqueResults(), it works for most places but fails to insert data in some cases. Hence I wanted to do it the old-school JDBC way.

Comment: @RanganathKini: `session.connection()` returns the underlying JDBC connection so, yes, it will work within the boundaries of the current transaction.